# Вывод записей MySQL

Tags: mysql, переменные, вывод

Здравствуйте, Помогите пожалуйста.
Я хочу сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в меню, менялось значение id в PHP коде.

PHP код:

```
require ('config.php');

$result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `lekcii` WHERE id=1'); // запрос на 
выборку
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['title'].'</p>';// выводим данные    
echo $row['text'].'</p>';// выводим данные
}
```

МЕНЮ:

```
<li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Основы информатики</a><ul>
    <li><a href="#">Информация </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Кодирование информации </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Основы логики и логические элементы ЭВМ </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Моделирование и формализация </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Алгоритмизация и программирование </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Компьютер и программное обеспечение </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Компьютерные сети </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Социальная информатика </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

или стоит заменить ссылки чем то другим, вроде кнопок?
А то не хочется для каждой лекции создавать отдельную страницу.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понял что именно надо сделать =)

```
<?php
$id = $_GET[id];
require ('config.php');
$result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `lekcii` WHERE id='.$id);
?>

<li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Основы информатики</a><ul>

<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<li>';
echo '<a href="http://site.ru/index.php?id='.$rows['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a>';
echo $row['text'];
echo '<li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек, проблема решена)